# Azure Service Bus Request Time Out Issue

Tags: azure, azureservicebus

I am getting the time out error, when I called Azure Service Bus with the below code.
So I have applied retry logic, however still I am getting the time out error.

var msgFactory = MessagingFactory.CreateFromConnectionString(connection);
var namespaceManager = NamespaceManager.CreateFromConnectionString(connection);

if (!await namespaceManager.QueueExistsAsync(queueName))   //Time out Error

{///Code}

**The request has timed out after 60000 milliseconds. The successful completion of the request cannot be determined. Additional queries should be made to determine whether or not the operation has succeeded. TrackingId:143b4d25-e97c-4270-8714-93a4c6818fea,TimeStamp:1/19/2016 8:30:36 PM**

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just because a pair of parentheses missing in:

```
  if (!await namespaceManager.QueueExistsAsync(queueName))
```

which should be:

```
 if (!(await namespaceManager.QueueExistsAsync(QueueName)))
```

Answer (score 0):

We need to run the pregame outside of the company firewall, then it will work.